# Separate Signal Values from Noise

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, denoising

let us consider following graph of singular values

[image]

i want to make  some kind of  clustering of these data,namely to  seperate  main components from non main components,let say signal components from noise components,i would like to do like this(any software matlab,etc is great,better matlab)let us start like this  ,first do linear regression  with first point,then do regression analysis with first two point and so on,point is that  one want to  create two group,in first group   coefficients of  regression lines should be  close to each other, also in another group  regression coefficients should be close to each other,but regression  coefficients  in one group must be different then coefficients in another group,that means that we should find such point which separate this group optimally,  in other word i should stop regression analysis at some point which  well separate  two group,and another regression will start from this stop point till other rest points,please help me how to do it programaticaly

Comment: By the way, it's common to present SVD eigenvalues in decrasing order, not as on your images. You can also try to use log-scale on Y axis when displaying SVD eigenvalues.

Comment: it is cumulative,not  itself singular value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is pretty broad and you didn't even mentioned that you're using [SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_Spectrum_Analysis) (at the moment).

You're asking for interpretaion of SSA decomposition. This topic is rather complex and pretty difficult to automate, but there are much information on this in chapter 2.4 "Choice of Parameters in Basic SSA" of the book [Singular Spectrum Analysis for Time Series](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-3-642-34912-6) by N. Golyandina & A. Zhigljavsky ([chapter 2](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642349126-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1373628-p174720085) is freely available).

You may also search by keywoard "**AutoSSA**" to get some related information.

By the way, SSA can not separate everything because there can be nonseparable components in the signal. Even noise can be nonseparable from the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition).
By looking at the Singular Values I'd determine which vectors spread the data and which spread the noise.

You may use approach like the [Elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)).

Practically, they both do both, but if we speak which are dominant, this would be a great starting point.

Comment: i have got  SVD exacting and they are singular values

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @datodatuashvili, Could you please mark my answer?